# How did the Tesseract come to Earth from Asgard?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012, captain-america-the-first-avenger

Wikis say that the Tesseract came to Earth accidentally. How exactly, did it come to Earth?

Comment: related to : [Why did Odin leave the Tesseract on Earth?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/why-did-odin-leave-the-tesseract-on-earth)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The opening sequence of *Captain America: The First Avenger*, combined with the historical information at the start of *Thor* provides the answer.  ~1000 years ago, Asgardians fought the Frost Giants on Earth as part of a cross-realm war.  During a later war (or perhaps later battles in that same war), roughly [600 years ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGmVD.jpg) the Tesseract was lost on Earth.

It was found by humans and hidden away in Norway.  At the start of *Captain America*, the Red Skull finds the Tesseract and makes use of it to power HYDRA's weapons.  In the end, it's dropped into the Atlantic ocean, and recovered by Tony Stark's father, Howard Stark.  SHIELD held on to it in modern times, unable to unlock its secrets. Then it was discovered by Loki (Thors Brother) who wanted its power and the Avengers had to stop him. And when they were done it was brought back to Asgard.

Comment: Why would Asgardians use Tesseract against Frost Giants? Wouldn't it be dangerous?

Comment: All weapons of war are dangerous. That's usually the point.

Comment: It does kind of seem like bringing a nuke to a knife fight, but I suppose we don't really know how tough Laufey was "back in the day."  Do we have any reason to believe it was *that* war that brought it to Earth, though, rather than some other as-yet-unmentioned event?  I doubt the war with the Frost Giants was Asgard's only contact with Midgard...

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of [Captain America: The First Avenger (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America%3a_The_First_Avenger), they show what seems to be a small house, or tomb if you will.  When the leader of HYDRA starts speaking, he talks about the "treasure room of Odin" Odin's prize in that room was the Tessaract, and Odin lost it while fighting his battle with the Frost Giants on Earth. It was found and encased with a leader of Europe when he died. When people found the tomb they protected it when the found out what it (the Tessaract) was from legend.

Comment: I edited this to remove the unnecessary comments and fix the formatting a little, but you should cite where you got your information from.

Comment: @Monty129 Does a movie title suffice as a citation?

Comment: @Paperjam If you roll back the edits to the original user16178 said (s)he "read it on the internet" citing what website the info was from would be better.