# Confusion on how the Tessaract got to Earth

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

How did the Red Skull on Earth get the Tessaract if Odin took it and locked it away in the weapons vault on Asgard after taking it from the frost giants in the first war? [avengers]

Comment: See also [Why did Odin leave the Tesseract on Earth?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/why-did-odin-leave-the-tesseract-on-earth)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what odin had was the casket of ancient winters not the tessaract. The tessaract was lost to odin on earth whilst he was battleing laufey and the frost giants. it was later found and encased with a leader of Europe when he died. When people of earth found the tomb they protected it after finding out it was from legend until the redskull took it and used it to form hydra in ww2.